# Send mail to one adress, forward to multiple adresses (Self hosted mailing list?)

Tags: email, mailing-list

We're a group of 25 people who sometimes need to send an email to each member of the group. I'm looking for a tool to manage the group members and forward/redirect emails.

If someone sends an email to groupname@myserver.com, it should be forwarded to each ouf our 25 email adresses. Only an admin should be able to add someone to or remove someone from the group.

We have a virtual server at a hosting company. It would be great if I could upload the tool and install/manage it from within the browser, but I'm fine with using SSH.

Summary of requirements:

- Send mail to one adress, forward to all adresses
- self-hosted
- 20-40 people
- 5-50 mails/month
- Email adresses may or may not be be visible for each other
- "Reply to all" behaviour is good enough

Comment: What do you use as mail server for SMTP? Can you upload/install a web app on that server? If you're using Postfix, I might have something for you.

Comment: I don't know/don't think so. Incoming/outgoing mail server is something like mail.myhostingcompany.com. On our server, fetchmail is the only piece of software already installed that seems to concern sending email.

Comment: Maybe you could check with your provider. With *PostfixAdmin*, there's a nice simple web front-end to Postfix for managing accounts. Setting up aliases with it is a breeze, and an alias can point to multiple addresses – which would fulfill your request perfectly.